# Online Audio annotation tools

Tags: annotation, labelling

I need to find a decent online annotation tool to transcribe audio.

There are some requirements for a potential tool:

- I should be able to deliver audio files to a few labelers. I should
- be able to track which files went to which labeler.
- It should be safe in terms of data storage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it meets all your criteria (mostly because I'm not sure I understand all your criteria!), but you could have a look at [ELAN](https://archive.mpi.nl/tla/elan):

> Description: With ELAN a user can add an unlimited number of textual
>   annotations to audio and/or video recordings. An annotation can be a
>   sentence, word or gloss, a comment, translation or a description of
>   any feature observed in the media. Annotations can be created on
>   multiple layers, called tiers. Tiers can be hierarchically
>   interconnected. An annotation can either be time-aligned to the media
>   or it can refer to other existing annotations. The content of
>   annotations consists of Unicode text and annotation documents are
>   stored in an XML format (EAF).

See also the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELAN_software) about ELAN. There is also a [Wikipedia list of related software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_qualitative_data_analysis_software), I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: thanks! ELAN looks great, but I need an online tool, rather than a one which needs to be installed

Comment: @Aidos oh right, I overlooked this requirement. there are a few web-based tools in the wikipedia list (last link), maybe it can help?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there, Spacy has a beta version of audio annotation interface so do check out. It's rather basic but may be enough for your use.